# Change a url parameter in the current state from ui-sref in angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using ui-router I would like to set a URL parameter no matter what state I'm in. A use-case for this is to switch between bookmarkable interface modes (e.g. "boring" or "funny").

I know it can be done using `ng-click` directive, but in this case I'm left with href-less anchors, which is not very useful.

I have tried the most obvious `ui-sref=".({foo:'bar'})"` but it fails with *"No reference point given for path '.'"*

Does ui-router have a native solution to do this? Ideally I would like to have something like:

```
<a ui-sref="currentState({interface:'boring'})">boring</a>
<a ui-sref="currentState({interface:'fun'})">fun</a>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that this functionality is available in the yet unreleased master branch of ui-router:

```
<a ui-sref="{foo:'bar'}">foobar</a>
```

See the related issue: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1031

Comment: Has this been released into production?

Comment: @Mika The issue is still open, so probably not. I haven't looked into it recently.

Comment: Yea looks that way. Did you end up using another branch in live or did you find another solution?

Comment: @Mika I honestly don't remember (it has been two years already). I think we decided to drop some project features due to issues around ui-sref.

Answer (score 5):

Or for the time being you can do something like this in the controller or in app run as I prefer to do it so it's available everywhere (each view):

```
appModule.run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(ev, to, toParams, from) {
            $rootScope.previousState = from.name;
            $rootScope.currentState = to.name;
        });
    });
```

Then should then be able to use:

```
<a ui-sref="{{currentState}}({interface:'boring'})">boring</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old topic but

```
ui-sref="."
```

should work.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/2541

Comment: Wow, that's about as easy as it gets!